# Not able to reset form

Tags: jquery, forms, plugins

I'm trying to reset my form. My reset button is for some reason not working:

```
<input id="btn_clearForm" type="reset" name="clearForm" value="Clear" />
```

So I've created this function to do the work:

```
jQuery('.clearButton').live('click',function () {
  clearForm(jQuery('#brand_data_form')); 
});

function clearForm(form) {
  jQuery(':input[type=text], :input[type=textarea]', form).val('');
  jQuery(':input[type=checkbox]', form).attr('checked', false);
  jQuery('select', form).attr('selectedIndex', -1);
  alert('test'); // <- At this point, the form is cleared
}
```

The problem is that after the `clearForm` function has run, the data is put back into the form.

I've added the `alert` so that I can monitor the clearing, and each form field is reset. But when it's finished, it all gets populated again.

I don't understand what's wrong here.

Comment: Is there a reason for *not* using a simple `<input type="reset" value="Reset the form" />` ([JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/kJRm8/2/)), or a `<button type="reset">Reset the form</button>` ([JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/kJRm8/1/)) button?

Comment: Because it's currently not working.

Comment: [Couldn't reproduce](http://jsfiddle.net/PYTdn/) - please post more code or make that jsFiddle reflect the same problem.

Comment: I dimplified the code. The form is reset. I'm just trying to figure out why all the data is put back after the function is done. Do I have to bind the action?

Comment: @Steven, while 'it' might not 'be working' (and please define what you mean by 'not working'), that doesn't address my question. HTML has an element, and attribute, specifically targeted towards the resetting of a form. I'm confused as to why you're using a jQuery function/plugin to effect an already-available, and in-built, function. **Edited** to add: @Steven, to notify Shadow Wizard of your response, use his name prefaced with the '@' symbol, as I've done with your name in this comment... =)

Comment: @Steven when exactly it get populated again? Just like that after x seconds? Does this also happen after to click the "native" reset button as suggested by David?

Comment: @shadow It gets populated imidietly after the function is done. I've tried the normal reset button, but for some reason it's not working.

Comment: @everybody See my comment to @BradBrening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 'reset' button will reset the form to the initial values.  You're looking to 'clear' the form, which is quite a bit different.  Since you're attaching your "clear" function to the "reset" button, the two functions would appear to be conflicting.  I'd change your input to type button and that should clear it up (no pun intended).

```
<input id="btn_clearForm" type="button" name="clearForm" value="Clear" />
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem. When page is loaded, the form is alread y populated. Clicking the reset button will therefore reset the form back to it's values. Changing it to a button and running my script solved the problem.